# Snapshot testing doesn't work Jest Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, snapshot

I am failing when running the snapshot test.

Below the component I am testing.

```
function Footer() {
  const windowWidth = useWindowSize().windowWidth;
  return (
    <footer
      style={{
        minWidth: windowWidth,
      }}
    >
      Made by XXX
    </footer>
  );
}
export default Footer;
```

This is the test I wrote

```
describe('Footer', () => {
  it('renders as expected', () =>{
    const tree = TestRenderer.create(<FooterView/>).toJSON();
    console.log(tree);
  });
});
```

And this is the error I am receiving.

```
Test suite failed to run
    SyntaxError: D:\MyProGit\frontend\src\__tests__\Footer.test.js: Unexpected token (8:37) at Parser.raise (C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:41:63)
```

I did the same steps given in tutorial[Testing React Apps](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react), but at the end, I can´t find file `babel.config.js`.

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.12.0"
  }
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
}
```

Comment: Show the `scripts` part of your `package.json`.  It's likely that Jest has no idea what JSX is.  Please see [Testing React Apps](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react).  If you don't configure JSX to be transpiled, it will generate a bunch of syntax errors.

Comment: Thank I am checking the link you sent. I saw only the page abot snapshoting and didnt notice the subpage about configuration.

Comment: @zero298 I did like in tutorial, but problem remains. I updated my question.

Comment: For sanity's sake, can you try `TestRenderer.create(React.createElement(FooterView));` instead of using JSX?

Comment: I tried, appeared error `Jest encountered an unexpected token.  This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript. (...) ({"Object.anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`